# Detect ETX characters using Java

Tags: java, hex

We have a text file with multiples paragraphs each separated by 
character **ETX** as shown in below image. The Java program should
 read each paragraph and parse and the end of paragaraph should be
 identified by ETX.

How to make Java recognize or detect the EXT character?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered looking it up in the ASCII table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ETX is an ASCII character, designed to indicate the end of transmission.

It also has the unicode codepoint `U+0003` and you can thus find it by searching your string for this codepoint. If you are working with 8-bit strings, search for `"\x03"`.

Comment: public static boolean isAllASCII(String input) {
     boolean isASCII = true;
     for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
      System.out.println(input.charAt(i));
         int c = input.charAt(i);
         System.out.println(c);
     }
     return isASCII;
 } ---- used this code, it just printing 3. How to identify the unicode U+0003. Can you please provide a sample code?

Comment: Exactly that way. Check that the character value is ``3``.

Answer (score 0):

String representation of ETX character is String.valueOf((char)3)

```
File file = new File("myfile.txt");
java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(file);
String etx = String.valueOf((char)3);
scanner.useDelimiter(etx);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String paragraph = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Paragraph = " + paragraph);
}
```